# How to decrypt the received data from serial to USB using python?

Tags: python, encryption, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, zigbee

When we send an message from zigbee which is connected to PC to another Zigbee which is connected to raspberry pi board.We are getting an message,similarly which i had sent from Zigbee Connected PC
for example:* Hello World *,but in receiver section i am getting Hello World with Encrypted data (with Header bit and Check-sum bit)
But i need Only Hello World in Receiver Terminal
*In Receiver Terminal Zigbee is connected to raspberry pi for that interfacing ,i am using Serial to USB cable.*
Here is my simple python code for Serial to USB

```
import serial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, rtscts=1, timeout=0)
while True:
       line = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
       if len(line) > 0:
                       print line
       sleep(1)
ser.close()
```

*I am getting type of Results ,do help*

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/iot/XBeeAPI/Python $ python temperlm.py 
~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�~#�}3�@ȶ���####��~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�
~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�
~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�
~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�
~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�
~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�
~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�
~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�~#�}3�@ȶ���#Hello World�
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
File "temperlm.py", line 9, in <module>
sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: It's not python problem, it's probably a sync frame, try to use some simple serial emulator like RS232Analyzer and test it manually before coding, also fix the indention at the post it will be easier to read :)

Comment: Dumping things as hex would help, e.g. `print " ".join(["%02X" % ord(x) for x in line])`

Comment: *"But i need Only Hello World ..."* -- You need to add a Zigbee protocol handler between your application program and reading the serial port.  That handler must find the start (and end) of each Zigbee message packet, validate the packet using the checksum, and then extract the payload (the bytes that you want) from the packet.  Or else use the AT command to put the device into modem transparent mode if it has that capability.

Comment: The data you're seeing should conform to this Zigbee receive packet frame: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/building-wireless-sensor/780596807757/zigbee_receive_packet.html, and terminated with a checksum byte.

Comment: Send me the proper code i am in bit confused state do help or u can edit my code also

Answer (score 0):

You have your XBee modules configured for "API Mode", which uses formatted packets of data instead of "Transparent Serial Mode" which just passes serial data straight through.  For simple applications or serial cable replacement, transparent serial mode is great.  Once you start doing more with the XBee module (like sending AT commands and communication with multiple devices on a network), you typically switch to API mode.

Look at the `ATAP` setting on the module -- `0` is for transparent serial, `1` is for API mode and `2` is for "escaped API mode" where certain characters are escaped to allow for easier detection of the start of a frame.

Be sure to read the XBee documentation about those modes to gain a better understanding of the differences and pros/cons of each.